# Python3.x: Zipping two lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to zip two lists by using the following code.

```
x= array([  56,   84,  112,  140,  168,  196,  224,  252,  280,  308,  336,
        364,  392,  420,  448,  476,  504,  532,  560,  588,  616,  644,
        672,  700,  728,  756,  784,  812,  840,  868,  896,  924,  952,
        980, 1008, 1036, 1064, 1092, 1120, 1148, 1176, 1204, 1232, 1260,
       1288, 1316])
y= array([0.96780319, 0.97895697, 0.97842111, 0.97283027, 0.97018866,
       0.96909372, 0.96666816, 0.96606516, 0.96241692, 0.96401202,
       0.96687579, 0.9639144 , 0.96337408, 0.95347031, 0.94973264,
       0.94029729, 0.93110676, 0.91811095, 0.90408523, 0.89094813,
       0.86007405, 0.82883029, 0.81545714, 0.80478483, 0.78737364,
       0.75932569, 0.63460651, 0.47195082, 0.47093429, 0.55858831,
       0.88054987, 0.96316967, 0.93770625, 0.82751165, 0.76109564,
       0.73998599, 0.77669407, 0.785424  , 0.76852611, 0.78837932,
       0.79866485, 0.8308753 , 0.89322146, 0.92456099, 0.9673221 ,
       0.96211249])

zipped_list=[]
row = np.array([list for i in zip(x, y)])

for a, b in row:
    zipped_list.append((a,b))
```

I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-106-2294469b69dd>", line 4, in <module>
    for a, b in row:

TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

The desired outcome is paring x and y element by element

```
[(56,0.96780319), (84,0.97895697), (112,0.97842111)....(1316,0.96211249)]
```

Any suggestions on why the code is running into this error and how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Edit: I realized I missed (i) after list.
Instead of `row = np.array([list for i in zip(x, y)])`,

```
row = np.array([list (i) for i in zip(x, y)])
```

I missed (i) after list. Now with the corrected version (the latter). The code runs fine. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You have an array full of the Python type `list`. I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: What do you expect `[list for i in zip(x, y)]` to produce?

Comment: `list(zip(x,y))` gives you that output

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I added the edits. `[list for i in zip(x, y)]` wouldn't do anything, since it is missing the (i) after list. The following should work: `[list (i) for i in zip(x, y)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is what you are trying to get:

```
import numpy as np

    x= np.array([  56,   84,  112,  140,  168,  196,  224,  252,  280,  308,  336,
            364,  392,  420,  448,  476,  504,  532,  560,  588,  616,  644,
            672,  700,  728,  756,  784,  812,  840,  868,  896,  924,  952,
            980, 1008, 1036, 1064, 1092, 1120, 1148, 1176, 1204, 1232, 1260,
           1288, 1316])
    y= np.array([0.96780319, 0.97895697, 0.97842111, 0.97283027, 0.97018866,
           0.96909372, 0.96666816, 0.96606516, 0.96241692, 0.96401202,
           0.96687579, 0.9639144 , 0.96337408, 0.95347031, 0.94973264,
           0.94029729, 0.93110676, 0.91811095, 0.90408523, 0.89094813,
           0.86007405, 0.82883029, 0.81545714, 0.80478483, 0.78737364,
           0.75932569, 0.63460651, 0.47195082, 0.47093429, 0.55858831,
           0.88054987, 0.96316967, 0.93770625, 0.82751165, 0.76109564,
           0.73998599, 0.77669407, 0.785424  , 0.76852611, 0.78837932,
           0.79866485, 0.8308753 , 0.89322146, 0.92456099, 0.9673221 ,
           0.96211249])

    zipped_list = [i for i in zip(x, y)]

    print(zipped_list)
```